# How to fit this background image completely

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, resize

[The stripped background is just a little off on the left and I haven't been able to make it fit. Can someone help me out please? Thanks in advance!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMV5N.png)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" style="border-radius: 26px 3px 3px; background-color: #982d41">
      <h2>About</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:#d77082">
      <h2>Menu</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="border-radius: 0px 26px 3px 3px; background-color:#ecafa9">
      <h2>Blog</h2>
    </div>



    <div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Lyn's Site</h1> 
    <div class="container">
...      
</div>
  <p>Just a test</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.jumbotron {
  background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRCA3_YcNlv-lliZZBuZZfvYi-H-qQ_EIe7Qf5AXfyCq9xPcUZp);
  margin: auto; 
  height: 250px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 100%;  
}
```

EDIT: Thanks! I put background-size:cover at first but didn't notice the difference due to the white strips til I used a different image. Thanks again.

Comment: If the issue is remaining you can check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the background-size property :

```
background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

Added `background-size: cover;` to `.jumbotron`.

```css
.jumbotron {
  background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRCA3_YcNlv-lliZZBuZZfvYi-H-qQ_EIe7Qf5AXfyCq9xPcUZp);
  background-size: cover;
  margin: auto;
  height: 250px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" style="border-radius: 26px 3px 3px; background-color: #982d41">
      <h2>About</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:#d77082">
      <h2>Menu</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="border-radius: 0px 26px 3px 3px; background-color:#ecafa9">
      <h2>Blog</h2>
    </div>



    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>Lyn's Site</h1>
      <div class="container">
        ...
      </div>
      <p>Just a test</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this code**

background: url() center center repeat-x;

```css
.jumbotron {
  background: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRCA3_YcNlv-lliZZBuZZfvYi-H-qQ_EIe7Qf5AXfyCq9xPcUZp) center center repeat-x;
  height: 250px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 100%;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" style="border-radius: 26px 3px 3px; background-color: #982d41">
      <h2>About</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:#d77082">
      <h2>Menu</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="border-radius: 0px 26px 3px 3px; background-color:#ecafa9">
      <h2>Blog</h2>
    </div>



    <div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Lyn's Site</h1> 
    <div class="container">
...      
</div>
  <p>Just a test</p>
</div>
```